# How to achieve correct folder listing in C++

Tags: c, winapi

## include "stdafx.h"

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
   HANDLE hFind;
   printf ("Target file is %s.\n", argv[1]);
   
   hFind = FindFirstFile(argv[1], &FindFileData); 
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
      printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
       system("pause");
      return;
   } 
   else 
   {
   do
          {
          printf("%s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);            
          }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind,&FindFileData)!=0);
   FindClose(hFind);
   }
   system("pause");
   FindClose(hFind);
}
```

I need to get a folder list in output, but it gives me the following:

```
.
.
f
f
f
```

Actually, my folder listing is:

```
.
..
file1
file2
file3
```

Why do i have only first letter of file name?
Thanks.

Comment: Why does this have a `C++` tag?

Comment: I was going to ask why it has the C tag, but that code is clearly C, not C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `_tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), FindFileData.cFileName)`.

In your case `FindFileData.cFileName` is of actual type `wchar_t`, so with `printf` you are printing wide character string as if it were ascii.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a `TCHAR*` to a function expecting a `char*`. If you're compiling with `TCHAR` as `wchar_t`, every other byte in the string will be 0, so `printf` will see every other byte as a terminating null.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_tprintf` or `wprintf` instead of `printf`.